# Characterising singular homology among a more general class of cosimplicial spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, simplicial-stuff

> Is there a way to characterise (up to isomorphism) the cosimplicial spaces $F: \Delta \to \underline{\text{Top}}$ with $F( \underline{n}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ compact and $F(\underline{0})$ a point?
>   ${}$

If the above class is not too general, can - at least - the standard cosimplicial space, given by
$\Delta_n = \{(t_0, \dots, t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \: | \: t_i \geq 0, \sum t_i = 1 \} $
and the usual maps, be singled out in some way? (Or, if the class above is too general, may you suggest a more workable refinement using say 'convexity', 'connectedness', etc.?)

Comment: cross-listed: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575382/characterising-singular-homology-among-a-more-general-class-of-simplicial-spaces

Comment: No bites on math.se.

Comment: This question seems hopelessly general--for instance, it is at least as difficult as classifying arbitrary compact spaces that can embed in some $\mathbb{R}^n$.  What you refer to as "the standard simplicial space" is not a simplicial space but a cosimplicial space.

Comment: @Eric: yes, cosimplicial space! Thank you. Fixed now.

Comment: @Eric: regarding the generality, I figured as much. But as per my backup question, can you suggest a less general class?